Minecraft doesn't launch on python
project on github: https://github.com/Sesdear/DristLauncher/tree/main
My code:
import json
import os
import subprocess
# Function to find the Java executable
def find_java_executable():
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(["where", "java"], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
        output = result.stdout.strip()
        java_path = output.split("\n")[0]
        return java_path
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("Java executable not found.")
        return None

# Function to launch Minecraft
def launch_minecraft(username, max_memory):
    java_path = find_java_executable()
    if not java_path:
        return

    minecraft_jar_path = "versions/1.18.2/1.18.2.jar"
    memory_option = f"-Xmx{max_memory}M"

    subprocess.Popen([java_path, memory_option, "-jar", minecraft_jar_path, "--username", username])

# Open config.json and nickname.json files located one level above the current directory
config_path = "../data/config.json"
nickname_path = "../data/nickname.json"

with open(config_path, 'r') as f:
    max_mem = json.load(f)
with open(nickname_path, 'r') as f:
    nickname = json.load(f)

max_memory = max_mem["ram"]
username = nickname["nickname"]

# Launch Minecraft
launch_minecraft(username, max_memory)

I tried launch minecraft, but it give me a code 0 after start, i don't no to fix this

Note that zero is the usual code for success. If the java_path is not found then your code will just exit with zero. You should probably raise an Exception there instead. If this is for a multiplayer server you probably should also include the nogui argument.

How to add exeption?

Did you google "how to raise an exception in Python"?

no, it's client

Then you don't need to worry about the nogui bit. Rest of the comment is still relevant.

i add exception, and all the same code 0

The file to run minecraft is in versions, right?

Debug: Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.client.Main

"The file to run minecraft is in versions, right?" for a client? IDK. It almost certainly depends on your operating system (does for servers). That Java error is probably because AFAIK from googling that error message just now you can't launch the jar file directly, you have to use the minecraft launcher.
